# Is mold growing in my ductwork?

Tags: hvac, mold, ductwork

I am currently in a battle with my landlord over what I believe to be mold growing on the fiberglass liner of the ductwork in my apartment. He is having a specialist come to test it tomorrow, and I have picked up my own DIY mold test and am waiting for it to incubate and product results.

I want to get a community opinion though. I already know that it's not definitive without proper testing, but please offer your $0.02:

[image: duct]

Comment: Update: My wife and I moved out of this place after a huge ordeal with the landlord. He contracted for someone to come test for mold, and I was promised a copy of the report, but all I got was a phone call from the mold guy, saying "No, there's no mold there." He took an air quality sample only, and said that there probably was mold and that it was not worth worrying about. Since moving out, my wife and I have been healthier. All our stuff is currently in storage, and when we open any of the boxes, the odor is just horrid!

Comment: What climate zone?